# Open links in new tab on desktops but on the same tab on mobile

Tags: html

Is there any way to make links with "target=_blank" open in the same tab in mobiles only ?

For example, when we visit flipkart.com, all of its product detail page opens up in a new tab on desktops,  but it opens up in the same tab when accessed through mobile phones.

Comment: No, not using HTML alone. You'd need javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query with javascript or jquery or another library and tell after change window with remove attr target in html.

jquery code is like this:

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $('.yourselector').attr(target,'')
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

this code tell if windows with became 768 pixel, remove target attribute from a selector
**your selector is your class or id**